# Display ASP.Net MSChart / File Issue

Tags: asp.net, mschart

I’ve add *MSChart* to a webpage and I’m also using a Survey page I got from [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210304133542/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/061604-1.aspx).  Both work on my development machine but when I move them to my hosting site there are issues.

With *MSChart* page the chart is not displayed although it’s included the Page Source code:

```
src="/ClubInformationTracking/ChartImg.axd?i=chart_3d90c53b0f844807a2491a1d79a636a1_0.png&amp;g=75fecf0f14cf4121b623691d383263aa" alt="" style="height:300px;width:700px;border-width:0px;" />
```

And when I try to open the Survey page I get this:
Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'sstchur.web.survey' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

**Source Error:**

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix = "sstchur" Namespace = "sstchur.web.survey" Assembly = "sstchur.web.survey" %>
<%@ Page Language = "C#" %>
```

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly `sstchur.web.survey` could not be loaded.

**WRN:** Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value `[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]` (DWORD) to 1.

**Note:** There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

The Hosting site is using Version 4.0 and the dll needed for the survey is in the BIN directory.

When I moved my files to the hosting site I had to change every instance when I referred to a file from:

```
“~/FileName”
```

To

```
“FileName”
```

I’ve tried all of the “fixes” I could find for the *MSChart* that involved changes to the `web.config` file but because of the error messages associated with the Survey page I’m guessing this is the issue.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the content you uploaded and the `/Bin` folder you noted in the *root* directory of your website, or did you create a subfolder for this project?

Answer (score 0):

The /Bin folder is in a subdirectory.

Root/public/ClubInformationTracking/BIN

Comment: Not to be too picky, but a response to a comment should be made as a comment. (See the "Add comment" link beneath your question.)

Comment: I agree.  If there was an Add comment under my question I would have used it.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET only looks for DLLs in the application's root `/bin` folder. If you just added the `ClubInformationTracking` folder yourself and did *not* configure it to be an IIS application or virtual directory via the web hosting provider's control panel, then that is the problem, as ASP.NET is looking for any DLLs in `/Bin` (or, perhaps, `/public/Bin`, depending on how things are setup).

There are two possible remedies here:

- Move the `Bin` folder (and its contents) from the `ClubInformationTracking` subfolder into `public` and see if that works. If not, try moving it to `root`
- From the web hosting provider's control panel, make the `ClubInformationTracking` folder a virtual directory or IIS application. If you're unclear on how do to this, contact your web hosting provider's support.

Thanks, and happy programming!